# Visualize tree in bash, like the output of unix "tree"

Tags: python, bash, tree

Given input:

```
apple: banana eggplant
banana: cantaloupe durian
eggplant:
fig:
```

I would like to concatenate it into the format:

```
├─ apple
│  ├─ banana
│  │   ├─ cantaloupe
│  │   └─ durian
│  └─ eggplant
└─ fig
```

There may or may not be multiple root elements (in the above example, there are two root elements), and I would like to find a solution that handles them without an issue.

Are there any command line tools that can handle this kind of transformation? Failing that, is there anything in other scripting languages that can handle this somewhat easily (I've looked at Python's `pprint` but I'm not sure how to use it for something like this either)?

Comment: `pprint` will help your print out nicely. but not in this form i am afraid. is this form fixed or allow some sort of flexibility?

Comment: It doesn't have to be exactly like I have above, but it should match the style used by the Unix `tree` tool (i.e. printed as a hierarchy). The Unicode box-drawing characters can be replaced by standard ASCII characters if need be.

Comment: i just think of it, i found it's pretty easy. let me show you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

following code shall produce the tree structure you are asking for:

```
branch = '├'
pipe = '|'
end = '└'
dash = '─'


class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, tag):
        self.tag = tag


class Node(Tree):
    def __init__(self, tag, *nodes):
        super(Node, self).__init__(tag)
        self.nodes = list(nodes)


class Leaf(Tree):
    pass


def _draw_tree(tree, level, last=False, sup=[]):
    def update(left, i):
        if i < len(left):
            left[i] = '   '
        return left

    print ''.join(reduce(update, sup, ['{}  '.format(pipe)] * level)) \
          + (end if last else branch) + '{} '.format(dash) \
          + str(tree.tag)
    if isinstance(tree, Node):
        level += 1
        for node in tree.nodes[:-1]:
            _draw_tree(node, level, sup=sup)
        _draw_tree(tree.nodes[-1], level, True, [level] + sup)


def draw_tree(trees):
    for tree in trees[:-1]:
        _draw_tree(tree, 0)
    _draw_tree(trees[-1], 0, True, [0])
```

it requires you represent the data using given form.

---

about your data deserialization, you just need to keep track of the parent nodes, such that when a leaf appears to be a node, you just replace it:

```
class Track(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, idx):
        self.parent, self.idx = parent, idx


def parser(text):
    trees = []
    tracks = {}
    for line in text.splitlines():
        line = line.strip()
        key, value = map(lambda s: s.strip(), line.split(':', 1))
        nodes = value.split()
        if len(nodes):
            parent = Node(key)
            for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
                tracks[node] = Track(parent, i)
                parent.nodes.append(Leaf(node))
            curnode = parent
            if curnode.tag in tracks:
                t = tracks[curnode.tag]
                t.parent.nodes[t.idx] = curnode
            else:
                trees.append(curnode)
        else:
            curnode = Leaf(key)
            if curnode.tag in tracks:
                # well, how you want to handle it?
                pass # ignore
            else:
                trees.append(curnode)
    return trees
```

it runs:

```
>>> text='''apple: banana eggplant
banana: cantaloupe durian
eggplant:
fig:'''
>>> draw_tree(parser(text))
├─ apple
|  ├─ banana
|  |  ├─ cantaloupe
|  |  └─ durian
|  └─ eggplant
└─ fig
```

hope it fully deals with your problem.

---

## update

my code offers some concern over corner cases, for example:

```
>>> text='''apple: banana eggplant
banana: cantaloupe durian
eggplant:'''
>>> draw_tree(parser(text))
└─ apple
   ├─ banana
   |  ├─ cantaloupe
   |  └─ durian
   └─ eggplant
```

notice the left most side of subnodes of `apple`, there is no `|` to the end because they are suppressed.

or empty in the middle:

```
>>> text='''apple: banana
banana: cantaloupe durian
eggplant:'''
>>> draw_tree(parser(text))
├─ apple
|  └─ banana
|     ├─ cantaloupe
|     └─ durian
└─ eggplant
```

Comment: How would I best go about parsing the input format I gave above into the Python hash structure?

Comment: @CalebXu i don't know about your data representation. but just from the small piece you showed, it's just a matter of keeping track of the parent object.

Comment: The representation is the first thing mentioned in the question... "Given input". Having to reformat the input into the syntax in your answer seems like a tremendous hassle.

Comment: @l'L'l seems less tremendous than you think.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Maybe, although why the need to add more code then? :p Nice work on the fix/changes — it's *tremendously* improved over the previous version +1  :)

Answer (score 4):

This question is old, but here is a networkx version of the first solution:

```
def nx_ascii_tree(graph, key=None):
    """
    Creates an printable ascii representation of a directed tree / forest.

    Args:
        graph (nx.DiGraph): each node has at most one parent (
            i.e. graph must be a directed forest)
        key (str): if specified, uses this node attribute as a label instead of
            the id

    References:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151776/visualize-tree-in-bash-like-the-output-of-unix-tree

    Example:
        >>> import networkx as nx
        >>> graph = nx.dfs_tree(nx.balanced_tree(2, 2), 0)
        >>> text = nx_ascii_tree(graph)
        >>> print(text)
        └── 0
           ├── 1
           │  ├── 3
           │  └── 4
           └── 2
              ├── 5
              └── 6
    """
    import six
    import networkx as nx
    branch = '├─'
    pipe = '│'
    end = '└─'
    dash = '─'

    assert nx.is_forest(graph)
    assert nx.is_directed(graph)

    lines = []

    def _draw_tree_nx(graph, node, level, last=False, sup=[]):
        def update(left, i):
            if i < len(left):
                left[i] = '   '
            return left

        initial = ['{}  '.format(pipe)] * level
        parts = six.moves.reduce(update, sup, initial)
        prefix = ''.join(parts)
        if key is None:
            node_label = str(node)
        else:
            node_label = str(graph.nodes[node]['label'])

        suffix = '{} '.format(dash) + node_label
        if last:
            line = prefix + end + suffix
        else:
            line = prefix + branch + suffix
        lines.append(line)

        children = list(graph.succ[node])
        if children:
            level += 1
            for node in children[:-1]:
                _draw_tree_nx(graph, node, level, sup=sup)
            _draw_tree_nx(graph, children[-1], level, True, [level] + sup)

    def draw_tree(graph):
        source_nodes = [n for n in graph.nodes if graph.in_degree[n] == 0]
        if source_nodes:
            level = 0
            for node in source_nodes[:-1]:
                _draw_tree_nx(graph, node, level, last=False, sup=[])
            _draw_tree_nx(graph, source_nodes[-1], level, last=True, sup=[0])

    draw_tree(graph)
    text = '\n'.join(lines)
    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version for your reference.

- This version has a parser, but without very robust error checking.
- Based on the answer by @HuStmpHrrr, I also update the code to handle the 'empty corner' and 'empty in middle case'
- I also add read file from stdin, thus being able to integrate with bash script. You need to uncomment the last part . Suppose this script is called script.py, you can call `python script.py < test.txt` to read from file. The text.txt will store the text content you give.

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
  import sys
  input_str = """apple: banana eggplant
  banana: cantaloupe durian
  eggplant:
  fig:
  """
  leaf_end_str = '└─ '
  leaf_inner_str = '├─ '
  child_conn_str = '│  '
  empty_str = '   '

  #debug = True
  debug = False

  def recursive_print(cur_root, p2r_list, prefix, is_end=False, only_one=False):
      # first print current node
      if only_one or is_end:
          print '%s%s%s'%(prefix, leaf_end_str, cur_root)
      else:
          print '%s%s%s'%(prefix, leaf_inner_str, cur_root)

      if only_one == True:
          next_prefix = prefix + empty_str
      else:
          next_prefix = prefix + child_conn_str

      #print p2r_list[cur_root]
      if p2r_list.has_key(cur_root):
          next_only_one = ( len(p2r_list[cur_root]) == 1 )
          for child in p2r_list[cur_root]:
              next_is_end = (child == p2r_list[cur_root][-1] )
              recursive_print(child, p2r_list, next_prefix, is_end = next_is_end, only_one = next_only_one)

  def tree_print(content):
      # get root and parent-children relation
      root = {} # check whether a node is root
      p2r_list = {} # store the parent-child relation
      for line in content.split('\n'):
          line = line.strip()
          if line == "":
              continue

          ws = line.split(':') # separate parent and child
          if not root.has_key(ws[0]):
              root[ws[0]] = True
          if not p2r_list.has_key(ws[0]):
              p2r_list[ws[0]] = []
          if len(ws) > 1:
              for child in ws[1].strip().split(' '):
                  if child == '':
                      continue
                  root[child] = False
                  p2r_list[ws[0]].append(child)

      if debug:
          print root, '\n', p2r_list

      root_list = [r for r in root.keys() if root[r]]
      for r in root_list:
          if r == root_list[-1]:
              recursive_print(r, p2r_list, '', is_end = True, only_one=True)
          else:
              recursive_print(r, p2r_list,'')

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      tree_print(input_str )
      """
      content = sys.stdin.read()
      #print content
      if content != '':
          tree_print( content)
      #"""
  ```

Comment: The output for the node `fig` provided by this script is `├─ fig` when it should be `└─ fig`.

Comment: The bug is fixed by adding checking end of the same level