# Visualize Binary tree in bash terminal

Tags: python, terminal, tree, visualization, graph-visualization

When we learn binary trees we first try to understand the structure of what a binary tree looks like. Then we usually implement the tree according to need. We have to draw the tree in hand notes with pen and paper.

Let's take an example array `[1,3,4,6,7,8,10,14]`. If we construct the array into the Binary tree then the result is

- Preoder->  `[7, 4, 3, 1, 6, 10, 8, 14]`
- Inorder->  `[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14]`
- PostOder-> `[1, 3, 6, 4, 8, 14, 10, 7]`

My question is, there is any way or any python package to show the tree in the bash terminal, like this way

```
     Preorder tree
         7
        /  \
       /    \
      4      10
     / \    /  \
    3   6  8    14
   /
  1
```

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151776/visualize-tree-in-bash-like-the-output-of-unix-tree). It's drawing like a family tree but I expect the tree as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I have just [built one](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/tree-printer): it can be definitely improved but should be enough for small trees. If you find any bugs, let me know please.

---

There is an example on how to use it in the docstring of the `TreePrinter` class, but just to give you a preview of the final result:

You can build the tree in your question with (it is the same I put in `tester.py`):

```
from printer.tree_printer import Node, TreePrinter

n1 = Node(1)
n3 = Node(3, left=n1)
n6 = Node(6)
n8 = Node(8)
n14 = Node(14)
n4 = Node(4, left=n3, right=n6)
n10 = Node(10, left=n8, right=n14)
n7 = Node(7, left=n4, right=n10)
```

And print it using:

```
tv = TreePrinter(n7)
print(tv)
```

---

The output is:

```
        7 
        /\
     ---  --- 
     |       |
    4       10
    /\      /\
   -  -    -  - 
   |   |   |   |
  3   6   8   14
  /             
 -            
 |
1
```